# Angular: *ngFor iterate through Array Objects won't function

Tags: angular, typescript

i try to iterate trough my Array of data. Unfortunately i got no error message or anything like.

If i iterate trough an object i got still this error but elements got created:

```
Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.
```

For Fixxing this error i try to push the individual objects in an array.

```
export interface iProjectNewsData {
  id: number;
  ....
}

    
export class ProjectNewsComponent implements OnInit {
top3News: iProjectNewsData[] = [];

constructor(
  ....
  private projectNewsService: ProjectNewsService
) {
  this.projectNewsService.fetchTop3News().subscribe((data: any) => {
    data.forEach((item: iProjectNewsData) => {
      this.top3News.push(item);
    });
  });
}
```

Now my problem is (i think), the objects get pushed into array index 0. Why does it do not ++ the index ?

```
[]
  0: {id: 1, …}
  1: {id: 2, …}
  2: {id: 3, …}
  length: 3
  [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

The HTML Part:

```
<ng-container>    
    <div *ngFor="let news of top3News" [ngModel]="top3News" name="Top3NewsElement" ngDefaultControl>
       <img src="/assets/images/project-news/{{ news.image }}" class="w-full h-full rounded-top">
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML part, for which value you used in `*ngFor`? Thanks. While, you should move the code in the `constructor` to the `ngOnInit()` method, for applying the Angular Component lifecycle.

Comment: @YongShun thanks for your reply. Okay i has move the subscription into `ngOnInit()`. Additional i added the html part above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of reproducing, the problem is finally solved. I can now say the code was and is correct.

Almost shot myself in the leg for this....

```
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason your array doesn't include items that are iterable. Which is also confirmed by  `[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`. Your setting key : value in your array (which is invalid for an array, array can't hold keys, only items). If you want to have an Map in javascript it would need to be an object `{}`. My assumption is that `data: any` is an object and
`forEach` works for objects, so when pushing item in array `this.top3News.push(item);`you're actually pushing  `0: {id: 1, …}`. However if you do need the items with keys you can iterate over objects in template using `| keyvalue` pipe.

So let's get rid of the keys and only push values `v` = `{id: 1, …}`.

```js
  this.projectNewsService.fetchTop3News().subscribe((data: any) => {
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data) {
      this.top3News.push(v);
     }
  });
```

```html
<ng-container>    
    <div *ngFor="let news of top3News">
       <img src="/assets/images/project-news/{{ news?.image }}" class="w-full h-full rounded-top">
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and know how. What you say makes sense, but the result is still the same. The items get pushed into index 0. Loggin returns same result as my push into.

Comment: What do you get from `data: any`? Are you sure `src` is pointing at the right thing?

Comment: It returns: `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)` 

What do you mean with src is pointing right thing? For sure the source is correct.

Comment: Do these objects contain property `image`?

Comment: Yes, this is index 2: 
`2:
accesses: 54
author: "Francisca Towne"
created_at: "2022-08-05T21:26:17.000000Z"
id: 3
image: "notification-3.png"
last_editor: "Mark Drako"
likes: 13
nolikes: 2
reference: "this is the reference"
text_section_body: "..."
text_section_footer: "..."
text_section_top: "..."
title: "Forum Maintenance"
updated_at: "2022-08-05T21:26:17.000000Z"
url: ""
visible: true`